# PDO query not displaying results?

Tags: php, pdo

Okay so i am new to PDO statements so i am unsure if i have done a syntax error or whatnot. The php file does not show any errors:

```
<?php
    include('db_config.php');
    $itemName = 'Item1';

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM order WHERE itemName = $itemName;"; 
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {        
        echo $row['itemName'];
    }
?>
```

My objective is to pull an item using bootstraps datepicker, but for the purpose of this testing i am using the itemName.
The php file comes up blank?

I have checked the field names, db_config, and am unsure where the issue is coming from.

Please let me know if i have done an error in my statement or anything that seems wrong.

Comment: Wrap you `$itemName` with single quotes in the query or better use prepared statements .

Comment: *"The php file does not show any errors:"* - That's because you're not checking for them. Add `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order WHERE itemName = 'Sour Dough'' at line 1' in C:\WWW\htdocs\test\wholesale\php\getproduct.php:10 Stack trace: #0 C:\WWW\htdocs\test\wholesale\php\getproduct.php(10): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\WWW\htdocs\test\wholesale\php\getproduct.php on line 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you're using a [**MySQL reserved word**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), being `order` and it requires special attention; mainly using ticks around it.

Then since we're dealing with a string, `$itemName` needs to be wrapped in quotes.

```
<?php
    include('db_config.php');
    $itemName = 'Item1';

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE itemName = '$itemName';"; 
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {        
        echo $row['itemName'];
    }
?>
```

- Either use ticks around your table name, or rename it to "orders", it's not a reserved keyword.

> *"The php file does not show any errors:"*

That's because you're not checking for them.

Add `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened.

---

- Now, if you're going to use PDO, use [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

---

As per a comment you left under your question containing the MySQL error:

> 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order

- Read it `near 'order` it starts at "order".

---

Now, if ever your query should ever contain any character that MySQL will complain about, such as a quote etc. then you will need to escape your query and use prepared statements.

For example, if using:

```
$itemName = "Timmy's Sour Dough";
```

would translate to

```
WHERE itemName = 'Timmy's Sour Dough'
```

in turn throwing a syntax error.

So, it's best to immediately escape any data right away.

**Edit**

Your use of `prepare` and `new to PDO` collectively suggest that you are already trying to use prepared statements, just not the right way. You're just a little off from a well prepared statement. One correct way in your code would be

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE itemName = ? "; 
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute(array($itemName));
```

Notice how we have a `?` in your query then we are sending a value for it in your `execute` call. There you go :)

- Using [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) will take care of that.

Comment: ill make these changes kind of makes sense though with the reserve words

Comment: @Elevant Defiinitely ;-)

Comment: Great it finally was resolved, i didnt realise about the reserve words thing, thank you mate i will look the reserve works and such. I didnt really understand what you meant by surround by ticks.

Comment: @Elevant You're very much welcome, glad to have been of help, *cheers*

Comment: @Fred-ii mind if i make a small change to add 2 lines of code to this great answer at the end?

Comment: @Fred-ii- just made the edit. By any means remove it if you don't like it. +1

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Hanky웃Panky looks good to me ;-) and for the +1

Answer (score 1):

You're completely ignoring the main reason people use PDO. Prepared statements are what you should be using, which would make your query look like this:

```
$itemName = 'Item1';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM order WHERE itemName = ?"; 
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $item, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

<sup>*Read up on [`bindParam()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).*</sup>

---

In future, turn on your error reporting at the beginning of the script with this:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

That will save you a lot of time.

Comment: Even when using this method it doesnt seem to show. Does it make any difference if the field has 2 words?

Comment: I tried adding a try and catch but nothing showed up either. I am unsure if i correctly added the statement though

Comment: Using the Display Errors code you supplied still shows nothing? have i written this the statement the wrong way?

Comment: @Elevant Please see [@Fred's Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29909970/2518525)

Comment: @Fred-ii- He'll get there ;-) (Great answer btw, as per usual :P)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is an error in you sql statement. since itemName is either a varchar or text in your database, you need to put it in single quotes in the query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM order WHERE itemName = '$itemName';";
```

Comment: I tried adding the single Quotes but still nothing is showing up. The field is a VarChar.